# upload size increase not working (LAMP Docker)

Tags: php, linux, docker, docker-compose, lamp

cant upload +2m files

docker compose

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  web-server:
    build:
      dockerfile: php.Dockerfile
      context: .
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - "./html/:/var/www/html/"
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
  mysql-server:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rise
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysql-server
      PMA_USER: root
      PMA_PASSWORD: rise
      UPLOAD_LIMIT: 500M
    ports:
      - "8444:80"
volumes:
  mysql-data:
```

Php.dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.0-apache

RUN a2enmod rewrite

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git unzip zip


COPY --from=mlocati/php-extension-installer /usr/bin/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/
RUN install-php-extensions gd pdo_mysql bcmath zip intl opcache MySQLi

COPY --from=composer:2.0 /usr/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/composer
```

if you see the upload limit is 500mb but the php site dont want upload 2+mb files

follow guidens and add env but is not working.
dont finde the php.ini or the .htaccess

can you help me please

thx

Comment: You've set an upload limit in your phpmyadmin container based on the env var available for the given image. How exactly do you expect that setting to affect your php site running inside an other container with a totally different image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you added ENV var to the PhpAdmin container config only. But to upload file on site, the 'web-server' container is involved instead, right?

So you need to update the php.ini file of the 'web-server' container.

This can be done by mapping custom php.ini file from host to container. Values in this file will override any existing values. Add this lines to your docker-compose.yml, under the web-server:

```
volumes:
  - ./path/to/the/local/custom-php.ini:/path/to/the/folder/where/php/scans/additional/ini-files/custom-php.ini
```

Then create `./path/to/the/local/custom-php.ini` (path can be any) file and put there this line:

```
upload_max_filesize = 500M
```

After this you need to determine `/path/to/the/folder/where/php/scans/additional/ini-files/` folder. This can be done by running this command:

```
docker exec web-server php --ini
```

In the output you will see all the ini files used by php, and there will should be smth like "Scan for additional .ini files in: {path to folder}". This is the folder where you should map your custom-php.ini file, i.e. you need to replace `/path/to/the/folder/where/php/scans/additional/ini-files/` with this path.